# SQL storing current date only instead of selected date

Tags: html, mysql, sql

I have created following table named as 'persons' in sql.

```
CREATE TABLE `persons` (
  `personid` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `personname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `country` text NOT NULL,
  `MobileNo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `certification` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `EventDate` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

while i am trying to insert EventDate by html5 form it is storing only current date like 2020-07-09 although i have selected 2020-04-25. need some assistance please.

html code:

```
<div class="container row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mb-5">
<div class="admin-form shadow p-2 ">        
<form name="registration" action="new_registration.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="perspnname">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="personname" class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<label for="City">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="city"  class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<label for="Country">Country</label>
<input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<label for="event">Event:</label>
<input type="text" name="event" class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<label for="date">Event Date:</label>
<input type="date" name="eventdate" class="form-control" placeholder="" required />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Then show the code that is inserting. Without it we can't help you

Comment: *while i am trying to insert EventDate by html5 form* You must show HOW you do this. The code which gets entered date from the form and inserts data into the table.

Comment: please provide the complete code that is inserting the data into the table.

Comment: are you sure that there is intermediate script which is changing the value and you are posting the exact date?

Comment: Whatever gets saved into MySQL is determined by the specific SQL statement (`insert into persons ...` or `update persons ...`) you submit to the database server. MySQL won't peek into random files trying to figure out your intentions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks alot. It worked for me. I've figured out the problem.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is pretty much meaningless, which is just as well, as INT(100) would exceed the (estimated) number of atoms in the known universe. And why are you using MyISAM? Do you not care about data integrity?